# Symfony with Zend_Navigation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony1

Would it be a good Idea to use Symfony with Zend_Navigation ?
I already have integrated Zend Libs with Symfony

Comment: please clarify what you mean by "good idea", otherwise you are just asking for subjective opinion or Yes/No. What are your doubts?

Comment: @Enrico for ref, Symphony != Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Zend Navigation in Symfony is certainly possible, however the site would have to be of a significant size to warrant integrating a specific library for creating your navigation and breadcrumb.